# regex negative lookahead in capture group

Tags: regex, pcre

Im trying to capture a string of upper case characters but want to ignore if there is a lower case letter after the upper case letter

For example
for the string `ABC ABC ABC ABc` it should capture `ABC ABC ABC` only because theres a lower case 'c' after the last AB

I tried `([A-Z ]+)` which captures `ABC ABC ABC AB`,

How do i add a negative lookahead in this context?

https://regex101.com/r/j8Arzu/12

Comment: try `(?<=[A-Z])[a-z]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `[A-Z]\b` at the end, to ensure that the match ends at a word boundary to the right of a word, without matching unnecessary spaces either. Note that there's no need for a capturing group here, you can leave that out entirely.

```
[A-Z ]+[A-Z]\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/j8Arzu/13

If the capital-letter substring may start with a space, then use the same technique at the beginning of the string - lead with `\b[A-Z]`:

```
\b[A-Z][A-Z ]*[A-Z]\b
```

If you *additionally* may have only a single character matched, then put the second and third character sets `[A-Z ]*[A-Z]` into an optional group:

```
\b[A-Z](?:[A-Z ]*[A-Z])?\b
```

Comment: This will match spaces at the beginning of the string, like " ABC"

Comment: `\b[A-Z][A-Z ]*[A-Z]\b` will match ABC and AB, but not A.

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundaries `\b` to avoid matching partial words, and use a lookahead and a negative lookbehind to avoid spaces at the beginning and at the end.

```
(?! )\b[A-Z ]+\b(?<! )
```

https://regex101.com/r/Gf37Zk/1

Answer (score 1):

To capture only continuous uppercase letters you can try this regex: `/\b[A-Z]+\b/g`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/W0VE7U/1